# Need guidance in using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

When I run the below SQL, I'm getting results mentioned below:

```
SELECT  distinct id,date,col_t FROM table1
WHERE col_t LIKE '%true%'
OR col_t LIKE '%https%'
OR col_t LIKE '%.html%'
OR col_t LIKE '%.html%'
OR col_t LIKE '%_____%' 
OR col_t LIKE '%null%'

ID     DATE                  COL_T

1     2022-02-02              true
2     2022-02-02              true
3     2022-02-02              PROMOTIONhttps://www.redbus.com/home
4     2022-02-02              google_goog_ob_27pc4https://www.google.com
5     2022-02-02              goog_gl_a1_store_id.html
6     2022-02-02              abc_xyz_def-example_____
7     2022-02-02              elp_car_parking_____
8     2022-02-02              elp1_car2_sum-grill_____
9     2022-02-02              two_abcd_slp_1_null_null_null_null
```

I want to replace true values with NULL and others with empty string ''.
Can I use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to get the desired output?

I tried using

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(COL_T,'\.html|http.*$|_null.*$|____.$|true','')
```

AS COL_T. But I'm not getting accurate results.The results should look like below:

```
    ID     DATE                  COL_T


1     2022-02-02              NULL
2     2022-02-02              NULL
3     2022-02-02              PROMOTION
4     2022-02-02              google_goog_ob_27pc4
5     2022-02-02              goog_gl_a1_store_id
6     2022-02-02              abc_xyz_def-example
7     2022-02-02              elp_car_parking
8     2022-02-02              elp1_car2_sum-grill
9     2022-02-02              two_abcd_slp_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Replace instead:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html

```
SELECT  distinct id,
        date,
        CASE 
            WHEN col_t = 'true' then REPLACE(col_t, 'true', '')
            WHEN col_t = '*.html' then REPLACE(col_t, '*.html', '')
            ELSE NULL
        col_t 
FROM table1
WHERE 
        col_t LIKE '%true%'
    OR  col_t LIKE '%https%'
    OR  col_t LIKE '%.html%'
    OR  col_t LIKE '%.html%'
    OR  col_t LIKE '%_____%' 
    OR  col_t LIKE '%null%'
```